# R regex store variables?

Tags: regex, r, variables

Is it possible to use stored variables in R's regex?

For example I want to remove quotes around decimal numbers in the following string `s = "\"Bob\",\"1\",\"Mary\",\"2\""` - in most languages you could do something like `sub("\"(\d)\"","$1",s)` but I cannot seem to find the capability in R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also as a side question does R have the `\d` support? (it throws an error when i try it) Thanks

Comment: Yes, R supports `\d` but you need to escape the \, so write `\\d`

Comment: You can also use `[:digits:]` to match numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is usually called back referencing.  In R, you can use \\1 \\2, etc.

```
re.examples <- c(
    'What_are_we_doing?',
    'Woe, that a young fowl should fly the coop',
    '2011/12/24',
    'Subject: More information, then less important stuff.' 
)

sub("([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)","Year is \\1 Month is \\2 Day is \\3",re.examples[3])
sub("^([A-Za-z ]+): ([A-Za-z ]+), ([A-Za-z ]+).$","\\2",re.examples[4])
```

---

I'm not sure about \d support in R.  I generally just use [0-9] anyway, since I know it works and I find it easier to read.

Edit: @Andrie and @Richie Cotton both offered two suggestions in comments, which I will include here for completeness.  [:digits:] works, but to my mind offers little in readability over [0-9].  \\d works as well.