# R- regexp question

Tags: regex, r

I need to re-shape my data frame using regexp and, in particular, this kind of line

```
X21_GS04.A.mzdata
```

must became:

```
GS04.A
```

I tryed

```
pluto <- sub('^X[0-90_]+','', my.data.frame$File.Name, perl=TRUE)
```

and it works; than I tryed

```
pluto <- sub('.mzdata$','', my.data.frame$File.Name, perl=TRUE)
```

and it works too.

The problem is that I have no idea how to combine the two code in one, I tryed a script such this

```
pluto <- sub('^X[0-90_]+ | .mzdata$','', my.data.frame$File.Name, perl=TRUE)
```

but nothing appens.
Can someone say to me where I wrong??

Best
Riccardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove space in your regex. Also escape `.` char: `\.`, i.e.:

```
^X[0-9]+_|\.mzdata$
```

Comment: don't you need two escape characters before the dot, i.e., `\\.mzdata$`in R?

Comment: @Henrik, Why? `\.` it escapes char `.` of regex. I have no idea, needs char `\\` to be escaped in R.

Comment: on my pc, neither works in R. Your version throws an error (Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "^X[0-9]+_|\.") and with `\\.` it does not delete the .mzdata part. Normally you always need two `\\ ` in R as an escape character to escape the `\ ` itself.

Comment: @Henrik, I don't know R, you can ask OP what code does he use. I only provide valid tested regex.

Answer (score 9):

The regular expression you’re after is this:

```
^X\d+_(.*)\.mzdata$
```

This will match *your whole expression* and capture the part that you want to retain in a group. You can now replace this by `\1` (a reference to the capture group).

In R, this would be:

```
result <- sub('^X\\d+_(.*)\\.mzdata$', '\\1', my.data.frame$File.Name, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I haven't clearly understand what you have done but I thank you!!

Comment: The key to Konrad's answer is back referencing.  See this recent discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757465/r-regex-store-variables/6757892#6757892